# Direct indexing into 2d Numpy array using another Numpy array as the (y,x) coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I searched around if this is possible... It seems pretty straightforward so maybe I missed something.

I have a 2D numpy array:

```
#####################################
################################FFFF#
################################....#
################################....#
################################....#
################################....#
#S..................................#
#S..................................#
#S..................................#
#S..................................#
#####################################
```

I'd like to replace one of the 'S' with an '@' symbol.  I wrote a function to find the index of one 'S':

```
def findStart(env):
    y = np.nonzero(env == 'S')[0]
    x = np.nonzero(env == 'S')[1]

    y = [round(len(y)/2)]
    x = [round(len(y)/2)]
    return y,x

yStart,xStart = findStart(env)
```

which yields:

```
print('Starting point [y,x]: ', yStart,',',xStart)
Starting point [yStart,xStart]:  8 , 1
```

then I create a numpy array:

```
startCoord = np.array([yStart,xStart])
```

and I want to simply access env[yStart, xStart] using startCoord, like so:

```
env[startCoord] = '@'
```

which should return the following:

```
#####################################
################################FFFF#
################################....#
################################....#
################################....#
################################....#
#S..................................#
#S..................................#
#@..................................#
#S..................................#
#####################################
```

I've tried using np.put and and np.flatten but the '@' gets placed in the wrong spot.  What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: is there a reason you are determining which S to replace in this way?

Comment: @DerekEden not particularly.  I wanted to maintain the coordinates as one object, hence the use of startCoord.  Down the line, I need to use more coordinates so I'd really like to know how to access the array using startCoord.  As for how I am replacing it, the reason is I'm a python nooby and unaware of a better option! :)

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment...this might be an approach that could help you:

say your array is called `arr`

```
import random
ids = np.where(np.equal(arr,'S'))
ids = [(row,col) for row,col in zip(ids[0],ids[1])] #might be a better way to do this
rand_id = random.sample(ids,1)[0]
arr[rand_id] = '@'
```

here, `rand_id` is a randomly chosen row,col position in `arr` that contains your desired value to change...ids contains all row,col positions with this value

the second step defining ids just put them into a list of row,col tuples